# is 1 greater than i?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm not sure this question even makes sense because complex numbers are a plane instead of a line. The magnitudes are obviously the same because i is a unit vector, but is there any inequality you can write about an imaginary number and a real number without just using their magnitudes?

Comment: Commenting here rather than in the individual answers:  There's no total ordering on $\mathbb C$ that is compatible with the field structure.   We can impose any arbitrary total ordering on $\mathbb C$ if we wanted to,, but it would be relatively meaningless

Comment: *Is $1$ greater than i ?* - No. No $1$ is greater than *i*. :-)

Comment: @Lucian: Well played!

Answer (score 1):

An order in a field must have this property:
$$x,y>0\implies xy>0$$

Since $i^2=-1<0$, if $\Bbb C$ could be ordered as a field, we'd have that $i<0$, but then $-i>0$ and $(-i)^2=-1<0$. The conclusion is that $\Bbb C$ is not an ordered field.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the magnitudes which you said that you know are equal, there is nothing left to compare their size.

Answer (score 0):

When we go from real numbers to complex numbers, we lose ordering of values.

You cannot compare between two non-real values or between a real and non-real value. So, you cannot compare $i$ and $1$ since $i$ is non-real while $1$ is real.

The only thing you can compare is their absolute values.

$$|i|=|1|=1$$

But that doesn't give any comparison between $1$ and $i$.

Comment: You can of course measure their respective magnitudes.

Answer (score 0):

**i** is plotted on **Y axis of** of ***Argand plain*** and **1** is plotted on ***X axis***. So , it is not possible to compare both of them.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is not: [no total order exists on $\mathbb{C}$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Complex_Numbers_cannot_be_Totally_Ordered).